# SQL SERVER login Time out, unable to connect (OS LINUX SERVER)

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu

Actually I'm not good at Linux integration. But somehow I managed it. But last few days I have been facing this issue, SQL Server is not connecting with my app. Having error

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server))" --->

I am very much worried about my data which is very important to me. 
I also checked instance name and password which is correct.

[image]

[image]

What I found is SQL Server services is down. I tried to up and restart many times but didn't work for me. Also tried to search everywhere even I complained on digital ocean. But did not get proper response.

Even I do not have backup of my database.

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question.  Perhaps https://dba.stackexchange.com/ would be a better forum for this question.